# Having troubles detecting when a certain audio plays from the desktops output

Tags: python, pyaudio

I am currently writing a piece of software to detect whether a certain sound was played on a computer, if True it would change a setting in a certain software. So far I have this:

```
    wf = wave.open("PATH\\TO\\FILE", "rb")
        amountFrames = 100 
        sframes = wf.readframes(amountFrames)

        currentSoundFrame = 0

        chunk = 1024  
        sample_format = pyaudio.paInt16
        channels = 2
        fs = 44100 
        seconds = 3

        self.p = pyaudio.PyAudio()  


        stream = self.p.open(format=sample_format,
                        channels=channels,
                        rate=fs,
                        frames_per_buffer=chunk,
                        input=True,input_device_index=0)

        while True:
            # Store data in chunks for 3 seconds
            for i in range(0, int(fs / chunk * seconds)):
                data = stream.read(chunk)
                if data == sframes[currentSoundFrame]:
                    currentSoundFrame += 1
                    if currentSoundFrame == len(sframes): 
                        print("Sound was played!")
                        break
                    else:
                        print('Sound not played')
                sframes.append(data)

            
            stream.stop_stream()
            stream.close()
            self.p.terminate()
```

When I run the code I get two separate errors:

1. From `data = stream.read(chunk)`, I get `OSError: [Errno -9988] Stream closed`
2. From `sframes.append(data)`, I get `AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'append'`

With these errors I have not been test whether it does detect or not. Would love your expertise on this.

Comment: Re the second error, you can concatenate but not append bytes, e.g. `sframes += data` is probably what you mean. Re the first error, are you able to check whether the stream got read from at least once?

Comment: No I am not able to check if it got read once, how would I do that?
Also, thank you for the helping with the second error.

Comment: e.g. `print(data)` or some other feedback after `data = stream.read(chunk)`. Just to see whether the stream ever got opened or if it got closed for some reason before/after reading data.

Comment: Ok, so it does output some binary but then it still ultimately stops after about 1-2 seconds of printing out.

Comment: There are a couple of conceptual problems here.  First, you can't possibly keep up by comparing byte by byte.  You'd need to do larger comparisons.  But more than that, you're monitoring the microphone input to check for something coming out the speakers, right?  Many audio systems do "echo suppression" to suppress exactly this kind of feedback.  Even if they don't, what you get back is NOT going to be an exact match for the output.  It's going to be at a very different volume, with distortion from your environment, and ambient noise.

Comment: @TimRoberts Then what should I do?

Comment: @TimRoberts is right, I think.

Comment: With fancy audio cards, you can't do this at all, at least this way.  Even if you do catch the speaker with the mic, you will have to do way more sophisticated matching, by looking for the shape of the sound, not the exact byte values.  An FFT might help.  You also might investigate "loopback capture", which can let you intercept the stream going to the speakers before it leaves the computer.

Comment: @TimRoberts Can I just get it from the speaker output directly then?

Comment: That's what I just said.  You need to do some research on "audio loopback capture".  The mechanism varies by operating system and the audio system you're using.

Answer (score -1):

To print error #1, try rearranging the code to get rid of the `while True:` loop. It looks like you are trying to read to many times from the stream. To circumvent error #2, you need to concatenate rather than append to your bytes object.

```
newframes = b''
for data in stream.read(chunk):
    # Do something with data
    newframes += data
```

Also, consider using

```
with wave.open(filename, 'rb') as wf:
    # do something
```

Written like this the file is closed when the loop ends as well as if an error occurs in the loop.

Comment: This answer does not address the problems.  He shouldn't be appending to `sframes` at all; that's the read-only audio segment he's trying to match.

Comment: @TimRoberts, you are right. I have edited accordingly.

Comment: I appreciate that you're trying to patch your answer, but really you have missed the point.  His code (if it worked) verifies that the `data` matches what was already in `sframes`.  He doesn't need to save it, he already has it.

Comment: Seems as though, I may have to start over considering the issues you have highlighted.

Comment: @TimRoberts. I agree, however I like to think I helped OP resolve the two errors explicitly mentioned.